# Sony Xperia SP model not listed in 'developer.sonymobile.com/unlockbootloader' for bootloader unlocking

Tags: bootloader-lock, sony-xperia-sp

I don't know how I can unlock my Xperia SP phone, because the model is not listed in the site http://developer.sonymobile.com/unlockbootloader so I couldn't continue. My logic says there might be some model that is similar to this model (Xperia SP), but I don't know what model. Do you know?

Any suggestions **APPRECIATED :)**

Comment: Is bootloader unlock allowed? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPaXpzM-8vQ)

Comment: I must have 50 reputation to comment
So I should answer instead of commenting:
Yes, it is allowed :)